# how to convert jquery hide/show+animation to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want create a left side menu.

I want open and close it with a button.

Currently I use this Jquery code:

```
<script>
    $("#openMenu").click(function() {

    var menu = $("#menu");
    if ($(menu).is(":visible")) {
        $(menu).animate({width: 0}, 1000, function() {$(menu).hide();});
    } else {
        $(menu).show().animate({width: 200}, 1000);           
    }
});
    </script>
```

how can I do it with pure javascript?

Comment: for that you have to use **css**  `display` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gomzy says you can simply use the css display property to hide the menu.

However if you want to animate it you will need something like this:

```
(function () {
    var menu = {
        //Node is the menu container we wish to manipulate
        node : document.getElementById("menu"),
        //Is the menu open?
        open : false,
        //A handle for our interval
        interval : null,
        //How wide is the open menu?
        openWidth : 200,
        //How many pixels should we open/close with per frame? (speed of transition is determined here)
        pixelPerFrame : 10,
        //Load elements that has the "toggleMenu" class and bind a "onclick" event to them
        init : function () {
            //Self refer so we dont get confused when handling events
            var self = this;
            //Fetching elements
            var togglers = document.getElementsByClassName("toggleMenu");
            //Looping through the elements
            for (var a of togglers) {
                //Bind event
                a.onclick = function (e) {
                    //Here we need the "self" variable
                    self.toggle();
                }
            }
        },
        //Open/close the menu
        toggle : function () {
            //Self refer so we dont get confused when handling events
            var self = this;
            //If the menu doesn't yet have a width modifier, we assume the menu is open
            if (self.node.style.width == "") {
                self.node.style.width = self.openWidth + "px";
                self.open = true;
            }
            //Revert menu direction. Closes when the menu was open and opens if the menu was closed
            self.open = !self.open;
            //Clear any previous menus
            clearInterval(self.interval);
            //Setup the interval function
            self.interval = setInterval(function () {
                //If the menu is opening
                if (self.open) {
                    //Add the "pixelPerFrame" width to the current width of the menu
                    self.node.style.width = parseInt(parseInt(self.node.style.width.split("px")) + self.pixelPerFrame) + "px";
                    //If menu is as wide or wider than "openWidth", we set the width to "openWidth" and clears the interval
                    if (parseInt(self.node.style.width.split("px")) >= self.openWidth) {
                        self.node.style.width = self.openWith + "px";
                        clearInterval(self.interval);
                    }
                //If the menu is closing
                } else {
                    //Subtracts the "pixelPerFrame" width from the current width of the menu
                    self.node.style.width = parseInt(parseInt(self.node.style.width.split("px")) - self.pixelPerFrame) + "px";
                    //If menu is smaller than or equal to 0 pixels, we set the width to "0px" and clears the interval
                    if (parseInt(self.node.style.width.split("px")) <= 0) {
                        self.node.style.width = "0px";
                        clearInterval(self.interval);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000 / 60);
        }
    }
    //Runs init
    menu.init();
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g23zr90b/

Are there any specific reason why you don't want to use jQuery?